# MATLAB integration of vector field

Tags: matlab

Say I have a discrete vector field u(x,y) and v(x,y). I have another scalar field vort(x,y). x and y are a meshgrid style set of coordinates. I want to set a contour level of my scalar vort, and integrate the vector field around that closed contour. How can I do this when I have discrete data, not a function?

```
contour(x,y,vort,[0.5 0.5]); %for example
```

I can extract from this the data points at all locations on the contour, but how do I integrate the vector field onto this curve?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate the vector field (u,v) or the scalar field vort? The text of your question says one thing, the code example the other.

Comment: I want to integrate the vector field along the curve defined by the contour.

Comment: So, the aforementioned vort(x,y) is irrelevant to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted this by:

1. use `contourc` to find the coordinates of the points in the loop
2. use `improfile` to interpolate to find the u and v values at a specified number of points around the loop
3. Find the angle (a) of the loop at each point
4. Integrate u * cos(a) - v * sin(a) using `trapz`